# Website is not working on Mobile browser

Tags: php, javascript, android, iphone, wordpress

I am very new in Web development. I design a website `http://Jainbakers.com` . It is working fine on the desktop or laptop. When i am opening it into Mobile browser `(Android or iPhone)` it does not open it give me error response. So if any body can help me please help me. That website is design in `wordpress`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting this error: 500 Can't connect to mobi-bro.com:80 (Bad hostname 'mobi-bro.com')

Is there something redirecting your site to this domain when viewed on a mobile device?

Is your htaccess file redirecting? https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Comment: I changed my .htaccess file then it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone, when trying to access jainbakers.com I'm getting redirected to mobi-bro.com.
mobi-bro.com is not working neither on my phone nor on my desktop. So I think you should look into why this redirect takes place. Furthermore, when looking at the site in "responsive design view" (CTRL-SHIFT-M in Firefox) the site looks kinda messy, so you probably want to address that too.

Comment: One up just for mentioning responsive design view

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site redirects to

```
http://mobi-bro.com/l=3241101b056e0b4d03565714564f0e5820095d450a6e
```

for some browsers. The site mobi-bro.com doesn't seem to exist.